# How to store \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile on the public disk?

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate

I want to store an UploadedFile to the folder `/storage/app/public`. I'm using `file->storePubliclyAs()`, but it's storing at `/storage/app`. Using `file->storeAs()` gives the same effect.

Probably that'd be possible using `Storage::disk('public')->write(url, file)`, though it'd be easier if I could just use a method like `file->storeAs()`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify public folder

```
file->storeAs('public')
```